# How to join values in array from specified index?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I am new to C#. I have a phone number as a string value from API as `+12 122 23456 2`. I am trying to split the string and join the remaining values in to and produce something as `+12 122234562`. I know this in Javascript and following the same way, but doesn't work.

I tried:

```
string x = "+12 122 23456 2";
string[] y = x.Split(" ");
string z = y[0];
//I don't know the length of this array might be constant. I know I can do a for loop based on the length. But, it looks like too many lines of code for simple thing.
string j = y[1] +y[2]+y[3]
//I need something like this or even more easier way
string k = y.join(1 to leftovervalues);
```

How can I do this? Also, is there a simple way instead of writing too many lines of code.

Comment: Please provide some real code. `split` doesn't exist, nor does `join` (or even `Join`) as an instance method of `string`.

Comment: PLs see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0

Comment: @MansurKurtov Sorry about that. I was just explaining my concept and I forgot about the syntax. I am a JS programmer and trying to do in the same format. But, doesnt work ofcourse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
string k = y[0] + " " + string.Join(string.Empty, y.Skip(1));
```

`y.Skip(1)` will take every element after the first one.

Note that `.Skip(...)` is a LINQ method so you will need `using System.Linq;` at the top of your code file.